# Use Datastore Entity's ID or Key in ProtoRPC.Message

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

When transmitting references to other Datastore entities using the Message class from ProtoRPC, should I use `str(key)` or `key.id()`. The first one is a String the second one is a long.

Does it make any difference in the end? Are there any restrictions?

It appears that when filtering queries, the same results come out.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what your goal is and whether or not you're using `db` or `nbd`.

If you use `str(key)` you'll get an entity key and will need to construct a new key (on the server depending on that value). Using `ndb`, I would recommend using `key.urlsafe()` to be explicit and then `ndb.Key(urlsafe=value)` to create the new key. Unfortunately the best you can do with `db` is `str(key)` and `db.Key(string_value)`.

Using `key.id()` also depends on `ndb` or `db`. If you are using `db` you know this value will be an integer (and that `key.name()` will be a string) but if you are using `ndb` it could be either an integer or a string. In that case, you should use `key.integer_id()` or `key.string_id()`. In either case, if you turn integers into strings, this will require manually casting back to an integer before retrieving entities or setting keys; e.g. `MyModel.get_by_id(int(value))`

If I were to make a **recommendation**, I would advise you to be explicit about your IDs, pay attention to the way they are allocated and give these opaque values to the user in the API. If you want to let App Engine allocate IDs for you use `protorpc.messages.IntegerField` to represent these rather than casting to a string.

Also, **PLEASE** switch from `db` to `ndb` if you haven't already.

Comment: I am currently using db. Since it is only for a school project, I will probably stick to this, but i will keep it mind for my next projects. For now the ID are allocated automatically and I get either the string or the integer one. When I retrieve entity from the datastore, I just filter on the __key__ field... Is this wrong?